# Using app icon to return to main activity in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used the code snippet from "developer.android.com - Providing up Navigation" to implement a home button on clicking my app icon. It works in all my activities except in my fragments. I put this "getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);" in all activities, including my Fragment activity, which implements 3 fragments and edited the android manifest accordingly.

Is there a way to fix this or do I need a different approach to perform the same operation in fragments, since I can't reference the parent activity in the manifest for fragments?

```
<activity
   android:name=".ChildActivity"
   android:parentActivityName="com.example.test.MainScreenActivity" >
   <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
   <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
      android:value="com.example.test.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fragments you should access the parent activity to do such:

```
getActivity().getActionbar().whateverYouWant();
```

Comment: That does work but I still can't reference the parent activity in the manifest like for other activites..

Comment: @Acejakk It's another question, make another question on SO.

Comment: It is actually the same purpose. Clicking the icon to return to the main screen from fragments

Comment: @Acejakk I think you need to finish the current activity in order to return to previous one. `getActivity().finish();`

Answer (score 0):

The aswer is, you do not need to implement it for fragments at all. fragments are part of the activity and you only need to do it there, except you do it in your viewpager initialization:

```
// Initilization
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), args);

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Done!

Comment: Actually I was suspicious about it also, now would you accept my answer?